# When the conditions are all established,

Tags: word-choice

> When the conditions are all established,

I found that when conditions are met, the word "establish" can be used as a verb as the above example.

Other than "establish", when I write in technical documents, what verbs can I use?

Comment: "When the conditions have been *met*," or "When the conditions have *obtained*," or "When the conditions have been *satisfied*"

Comment: In a technical document, I use "fulfilled". But, "satisfied" or "met" are also appropriate. "established" conveys the idea of an evolution of the conditions, from an unestablished state to a state where conditions are met.

Comment: @Silenus Thank you very much. I couldn't come up with these words.

Comment: @Graffito Thank you very much. I also did not come up with "fulfilled". Also thank you about the meaning / usage of "established".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer

> When all the conditions are met

or

> When all the conditions are satisfied

I would recommend the latter if you are writing something about mathematical logic.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not come up with "satisfied". I am thinking to use this for document related to coding / software.